# Cannot read property 'drawing' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, angular6

I am using **AGM map** to draw the customize boundary of area using Drawing tools provided by Google.

**This is my code snippet**.

```
  AgmCoreModule.forRoot({
  apiKey: 'here my api_key',
  libraries: ['visualization', 'places', 'drawing']
})
```

```js
 ngAfterViewInit() {
  //debugger;
    this.mapsAPILoader.load().then(() => {
      // tslint:disable-next-line:no-debugger
     // debugger;
           this.handleGoogleMapApi(map);

    });
  }

  handleGoogleMapApi(google) {
     this.map1 = google;
    // tslint:disable-next-line:no-debugger
    debugger;
     const drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
      drawingMode: google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON,
      drawingControl: true,
      drawingControlOptions: {
        position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER,
        drawingModes: [
          google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.MARKER,
          google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.CIRCLE,
          google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON,
          google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYLINE,
          google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.RECTANGLE
        ]
      },
      circleOptions: {
        fillColor: '#ffff00',
        fillOpacity: 1,
        strokeWeight: 5,
        clickable: false,
        editable: true,
        zIndex: 1
      }
    });
    drawingManager.setMap(this.map1);
  }
```

**below is my console error**
[image]

Any help is appreciated...

Comment: Include the libraries=drawing  `<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=drawing">`

Comment: @Sachink already added this

Comment: I have Noticed, you are passing `map` to the function `handleGoogleMapApi(google)` taking `google` as variable change it to other i.e. `_google` and `this.map1 = _google`

Answer (score 1):

Hi from the error thrown your code is simply saying that 'google.maps' is undefined. I advice you to use console.log('google.maps'); to track the state of the object.

You may be missing a vital step while initializing the object.

Answer (score 0):

The variable `google` is over right with the function parameter `handleGoogleMapApi(google)`.

```js
  handleGoogleMapApi(_google) {
     this.map1 = _google;
    // tslint:disable-next-line:no-debugger
    debugger;
     const drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
      drawingMode: google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON,
      drawingControl: true,
      drawingControlOptions: {
        position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER,
        drawingModes: [
          google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.MARKER,
          google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.CIRCLE,
          google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON,
          google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYLINE,
          google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.RECTANGLE
        ]
      },
      circleOptions: {
        fillColor: '#ffff00',
        fillOpacity: 1,
        strokeWeight: 5,
        clickable: false,
        editable: true,
        zIndex: 1
      }
    });
    drawingManager.setMap(this.map1);
  }
```